# mDNS (Avahi) not working when hostname changed

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, mdns

With a new Raspbian Jessie 4.4 (4.4.38+ #938 Thu Dec 15 15:17:54 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux) OS installed and ssh enabled it is possible to access the machine with:

```
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

However if the hostname is changed in /etc/hostname (and /etc/hosts), for example to new_hostname01 (from raspberrypi), it is no longer accessible using `ssh pi@new_hostname01.local`.

```
$ ssh pi@new_hostname01.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname new_hostname01.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Both machines are connected to the network (can access the internet and previously each other).  I can't find any obvious tutorials or configuration to change.  There are several mentions of the old hostname `raspberrypi` in `/etc/ssh/` as the keys for the machine.  I deleted them all and successfully regenerated them [with this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/471335/112910).  I also reloaded the avahi-daemon with `sudo avahi-daemon -r` and tried rebooting the whole machine but so far I have always got the same error.

Additionally the advice about [finding other computers on the network](https://superuser.com/a/706070/148811) does not yield anything from Raspbian with changed or original `raspberrypi` hostnames.

(I'm posting here instead of on raspberrypi.stackexchange as it would make sense if this is a general ssh networking on Unix/Linux issue rather than one specific to Raspbian.  Happy to move it if it turns out otherwise.)

Comment: Change your new hostname to one with no underscore (`_`). Underscores are illegal characters in hostnames (dashes are allowed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `avahi-utils` and then run ([as suggested here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=7795&p=94439&hilit=avahi#p94439)):

```
$ avahi-browse -arp
```

This reported multi devices including:

```
+;wlan0;IPv4;newhostname01\032\091d4...\0580d\093;Workstation;local
=;wlan0;IPv4;newhostname01\032\091d4...\0580d\093;Workstation;local;newhostname01.local;192.168.0.40;9;
```

Trying to `ssh pi@newhostname01.local` works.

It seems host names with underscores are not allowed which makes sense as [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183140/539490), [rfc1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt) does not allow underscores in host names.